# SQL Query: call all results which start with a letter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to call all results which start with a letter, for example purposes it needs to be the letter 'A'

My SQL Query is below could you please explain what I need to add.

```
$sqlTest="SELECT * FROM tbl_usersTest";
```

I am still having some errors. My whole code is

```
$sqlTest= "SELECT * FROM tbl_usersTest WHERE name LIKE 'A%'; 
$resultTest = mysql_query($sqlTest);
$rowTest= mysql_fetch_array($resultTest);
$loopPhone = 0;

while($rowmytelcoTest = mysql_fetch_array($resultTest))
{
$loopPhone++;
$TestName = $rowTest['name'];
$TestImageUrl = $rowTest['imageUrl'];
?>
```

All fixed now thanks

The problem was the case sensitivity of the value , And I was also missing the " at the end.

Comment: I assumed it is mysql-related due to the tag he'd chosen

Comment: ok, what is the error you're now getting?

Comment: should the search be case-sensitive? According to the mysql docs "if any expression in a string comparison is case sensitive, the comparison is performed in case-sensitive fashion." so you could add "or like 'a%'" if need be.

Comment: The error I get, Soon as I add the WHERE LIKE part it does not display anything. If I remove it displays my data.

Comment: you are missing comma after your query just add double semi column and check 
"SELECT * FROM tbl_usersTest WHERE name LIKE 'A%'";

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from tbl_usersTest where col_name like 'A%';
```

where col_name is the relevant column.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to close your string properly:

```
// this:
$sqlTest= "SELECT * FROM tbl_usersTest WHERE name LIKE 'A%'";

// instead of this:
$sqlTest= "SELECT * FROM tbl_usersTest WHERE name LIKE 'A%';
```